# How to format a xml attribute to limit it to have only UPPER Case letters, numbers and dashes(-)?

Tags: java, xml, regex, servlets, gwt

One condition is that the string should not start with a dash "-".
I tried using the following approaches, could not do the required task

```
<attribute>
      <name>name</name>
      <label>Card-Id</label>

      <!--format>([A-Z\d]+)([A-Z\d\-]*)</format-->
      <!--format>[\p{Lu}\d]{1}[\p{Lu}\d\-]*</format-->
      <!-->format>([^a-z])[\p{Lu}\d]+[([^a-z])\p{Lu}\d\-]*</format-->

</attribute>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some samples of your input and expected output in each case? Also, are you using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 here? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, i'm not using xslt, just xml. So if we input a name, it should not start from "-" , only A-Z or 0-9 for the first character. And rest of the name can have many dashes or uppercase characters or digits.

Comment: The first one looks correct, although you shouldn't need the parentheses or `+`. One other option you could try is `[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9\-]*`. In what context are you using these regular expressions? Some framework? XSD?

Comment: You should edit your question and add the appropriate tags. Just [tag:xml] is not enough. At least [tag:regex] and tags that describe where you are going to use these expressions (XSD?, Java?, JavaScript?, ...) since different contexts support different subsets of RegEx. Adding the correct tags will make your question reach the people who can give you the best answers.